# Swap table cells between rows based on clicking position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am creating a table of two rows which each consist of 0s and 1s. I have created a function which allows the user to click onto two table cells and a button which swaps the two selected table cells.

I want to be able to swap the td elements from position 0 of a row to the table cell that is selected, and the same for the second row so that multiple table cells are swapped between two rows.

for example, if I select the sixth table cell in both rows, it should swap all the table cells from the beginning of the row to the sixth table cell

I have featured below the code which uses jQuery. Any help will be greatly appreciated:

```
<html>
<style>

body{
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
background-color: ivory;
}
table{
width:100px;

}
h1{
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 30px;
}
th{
border: 10px solid black;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 70px;
}
td{
border: 10px solid black;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 130px;

}

tr.center, td.center{
text-align: center;
}
td:not(.notSelectable) {
cursor: pointer
}

td.selected,
td.lastSelected {
background-color: yellow;
color: white;
}
</style>

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("table td:not(.notSelectable)").click(function() {
$(".lastSelected").removeClass("lastSelected");
$(".selected").toggleClass("selected lastSelected");
$(this).addClass("selected");
});
});

function swap() {

if ($(".selected, .lastSelected").length != 2) { return;  }


$("#lblSelectedDate").text($(".selected").siblings(".date").text());
    $("#lblLastSelectedDate").text($(".lastSelected").siblings(".date").text());

  // Set label with value data

   $("#lblSelectedValue").text($(".selected").children("input[type=hidden]").val());
       $("#lblLastSelectedValue").text($(".lastSelected").children("input[type=hidden]").val());

// Swap cell data
var temp = $(".lastSelected").html();
$(".lastSelected").html($(".selected").html());
$(".selected").html(temp);
$(".selected, .lastSelected").removeClass();
}
</script>

<body>
<button onclick="swap();">Crossover</button>
<br /><br />


<table border="1" align = "center">

<tbody>
<tr>

  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor = "#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <th>P1</th>

</tr>
<tr>

  <td bgcolor ="#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor= "#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor= "#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor= "#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor ="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor ="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor= "#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <td bgcolor ="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor= "#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
  <td bgcolor= "#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
  <th>P2</th>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to figure out what you need, If I am correct you want to swap td with content between 2 rows with same index, but it should swap all the tds starting from zero index till the selected td index among 2 rows.

If my above statement is correct, you must have requirement to select same td index in both rows, other wise uneven index selection will generate abnormality.

Check my complete working code here: 
https://github.com/helloritesh000/swap-table-cells-between-rows-based-on-clicking-position

Comment if required.

```
<pre>
    <script>
$(function() {
    $("table td:not(.notSelectable)").click(function() {
        var otherTrIndex = ($(this).closest('tr').index() == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        if($(this).closest('tr').find('td.selected').length >= 1 
        || $(this).closest('tr').find('td.lastSelected').length >= 1 
        || ($('td.selected').length > 0 
            && $($('table').find('tr')[otherTrIndex]).find('td.selected').length != ($(this).index() + 1)
                )
        )
        {
            return false;
        }
        $(".lastSelected").removeClass("lastSelected");
        $(".selected").toggleClass("selected lastSelected");
        for(i = 0; i <= $(this).index(); i++)
        {
            $($(this).closest('tr').find('td')[i]).addClass("selected");
        }
    });
});

function swap() {
    var selectedTd = $('td.selected');
    var lastSelectedTd = $('td.lastSelected');
    for(i = 0; i < selectedTd.length; i++)
    {
        var selectedTdHtml = selectedTd[i].outerHTML;
        selectedTd[i].outerHTML = lastSelectedTd[i].outerHTML;
        lastSelectedTd[i].outerHTML = selectedTdHtml;
    }

    $(".selected, .lastSelected").removeClass();
}
</script>

</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following demo will swap with the counterpart of the `.selected` cell (from either row -- bidirectionally). Details are commented in demo.

```js
// Counter
let id = 0;
// Click on any cell...
$('table td').on('click', function() {
  // Increment counter
  let idx = id++;
  // Get index of clicked cell
  let i = $(this).index();
  /* 
  Add/remove .selected to/from clicked cell and...
  ...add data-id attribute to it with the value of counter
  */
  $(this).toggleClass('selected').data('id', idx);
  // Find the clicked cell's counterpart
  let otherCell = $(this).closest('tr').siblings('tr').find('td').eq(i);
  // Give it the class .marked+counter
  otherCell.addClass(`marked${idx}`);
});

// When button is clicked...
$('button').on('click', function() {
  // On each .selected cell...
  $('.selected').each(function() {
    // Get .selected data-id
    let idx = $(this).data('id');
    // Find its counterpart
    let otherCell = $(`.marked${idx}`);
    // Get the value of .selected's hidden input
    let zer00ne = $(this).find(':hidden').val();
    // Get the value of counterpart's hidden value
    let other01 = otherCell.find(':hidden').val();
    // Replace the contents with one another
    $(this).html(`${other01}<input type="hidden" value="${other01}">`);
    otherCell.html(`${zer00ne}<input type="hidden" value="${zer00ne}">`);
  });
  // Cleanup all of the cells
  $('td').each(function() {
    this.className = '';
    $('.selected').removeData();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: ivory;
}

table {
  width: 100px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 30px;
}

th {
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 70px;
}

td {
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 130px;
}

tr.center,
td.center {
  text-align: center;
}

td:not(.notSelectable) {
  cursor: pointer
}

td.selected,
td.lastSelected {
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

td[class^=marked] {
  background-color: black;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<button>Crossover</button>
<br /><br />


<table border="1" align="center">

  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#4caf50">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <th>P1</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">1<input type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
      <td bgcolor="#ff0000">0<input type="hidden" value="0" /></td>
      <th>P2</th>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're assigning the value of one element to the other without first saving the original value. So both of them end up with the value of the second.